# PowerMock.expectNew with andAnwser instead of andReturn

Tags: easymock, powermock

I'm trying to use PowerMock with andAnswer to return a test stub instead of the original class, but it doesn't seem to work.  The test stub is a subclass of the original class.

```
expectNew(Foo.class, isA(String.class))).andAnswer(new IAnswer<Foo> {
    @Override
    public Foo answer() throws Throwable {
        return new FooStub((String)getCurrentArguments()[0]);
    }
}).anyTimes();
```

When the code tries to instantiate a new Foo, my answer method is never called and I get the following error:

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Must replay class Foo to get configured expectation.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The problem was that I wasn't calling replay for Foo.class.  The reason being that it was failing, saying that Foo.class wasn't a mock, but that was because I was calling EasyMock.replay() instead of PowerMock.replay().  After calling PowerMock.replay(), it now works as expected.

Comment: you should add that as the answer if you're able to.

Answer (score 0):

pass the invocation method argument and try the result calling invocation.getArugments[0]